# Не получается изменить св-во Text у Combobox из события OnSelect или OnChange

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! У меня такая проблема. В обработчике OnSelect (или OnChange) у Combobox я хочу изменить св-во Text, но не получается. Подскажите, как с этим можно бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так

```
 procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
Combobox1.Items.Add('Мой текст');
Combobox1.ItemIndex:=Сombobox1.Items.Count-1;
end;
```

Если нужен тот же индекс то

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
index:Integer;
begin
index:=Combobox1.ItemIndex;
Combobox1.Items.Strings[Index]:='Мой текст';
Combobox1.ItemIndex:=Index;
end;
```